# Can a component know its own DOM tree context?

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to write a `<Heading />` component that will abstract away some of the headaches of dealing with headings (h1, h2, etc) in conjunction with accessibility standards.

The goal being that this component would be able to dynamically choose a h(1,2,3) depending on its closest parent heading. However, Looking up the DOM tree like this remind me more of jQUERY than react. I've looked through the docs and SO but haven't seen anything about it, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

So the question is: Is it possible for a component to know where it is rendered in the DOM tree and then execute some logic with that info? (probably somewhere in componentWillMount).

Comment: Are you sure you want to programmatically pick HTML tags based on it’s position in the DOM? Sounds like over-engineering to me, and a CSS nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look upward in the DOM in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, but that's messy and uncontrolable.  There may be a better solution but this is the first thing that comes to mind.

```js
var headerFactories = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'].map(function(tag){ 
    return React.createFactory(tag)
});
var makeHeader = function(level){
    var make = function(){
        var factory = headerFactories[make.level] 
                   || headerFactories[headerFactories.length - 1];
        return factory.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    make.sub = function(){
        return makeHeader(make.level + 1);
    };
    make.level = level;
    return make;
}
```

The api may seem a bit strange, but let's say we have a Page component and an Article child which may have another Article child.

```js
var Page = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      // make a root level header
      var header = makeHeader(); 
      return <div>
        {header(null, "My Page")}
        <Article headerFactory={header.sub()} data={foo} subArticle={bar} />
      </div>
   }
});

var Article = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      var subArticle = false;

      if (this.props.subArticle) {
         subArticle = <Article headerFactory={this.props.headerFactory.sub()} />
      }

      return <div>
         {this.props.headerFactory(null, this.props.data.title)}
      </div>
   }
});
```

What happens is when we do `headerFactory(null, "foo")` we get a component of that header level.  When we call `.sub()` we get a version of that headerFactory with the next header level.

```js
var h1 = makeHeader();
var h2 = h1.sub();
var h3 = h2.sub();
var h4 = h3.sub();
```

This allows components to have header levels based on their parents without breaking out of React.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, as it's the only approach I've seen that could solve this. However, I don't know if the added overhead of calling `headerFactory` at every new node is worth it. I like the approach though.